# Time resolved memory footprint of TCL exec

Tags: tcl, fork

What's the high resolution time axis behavior of TCL 'exec ' ? 
I understand that a 'fork' command will be used which will at first create a copy of the memory image of the process and then proceed.

Here's the motivation for my question:

A user gave me following observation. A 64 GB machine has a TCL based tool interface running with 60GB memory used. (let's assume swap is small). At the TCL prompt he gives 'exec ls' and the process crashes with a memory error.

You insight is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Gert

Comment: Good question! _Tricky_ question too.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` command will call the `fork()` system call internally. This is usually OK, but might run out of memory when the OS is configured to not swap and the originating Tcl process is very large (or if there is very little slop room; it depends on the actual situation of course).

The ideas I have for reducing memory usage are to either using `vfork()` (by patching `tclUnixPipe.c`; you can define `USE_VFORK` in the makefile to enable that, and I don't know why that isn't used more widely) or by creating a helper process early on (*before* lots of memory is used) that will do the `exec`s on your main process's behalf. Here's how to do that latter option:

```
# This is setup done at the start
set forkerProcess [open "|tclsh" r+]
fconfigure $forkerProcess -buffering line -blocking 0
puts $forkerProcess {
    fconfigure stdout -buffering none
    set tcl_prompt1 ""
    set tcl_prompt2 ""
    set tcl_interactive 0
    proc exechelper args {
        catch {exec {*}$args} value options
        puts [list [list $value $options]]
    }
}
# TRICKY BIT: Yield and drain anything unwanted
after 25
read $forkerProcess

# Call this, just like exec, to run programs without memory hazards
proc do-exec args {
    global forkerProcess
    fconfigure $forkerProcess -blocking 1
    puts $forkerProcess [list exechelper {*}$args]
    set result [gets $forkerProcess]
    fconfigure $forkerProcess -blocking 0
    while {![info complete $result]} {
        append result \n [read $forkerProcess]
    }
    lassign [lindex $result 0] value options
    return -options $options $value
}
```

Comment: Found this comment: "With most current kernels, however, including Linux, the primary benefit of vfork has disappeared because of the way fork is implemented. Rather than copying the whole image when fork is executed, copy-on-write techniques are used." 
So it depends on the OS to some extent.

Comment: @BradLanam You'd think so, but it turns out that actual duplication costs are still a substantial issue. I see this more with Java applications (where working with pipes is _seriously annoying_) but the symptoms are pretty clear. OTOH, the issue with vfork is that the parent process is nowadays much less likely to halt and wait due to far more prevalent threading.

Comment: A call to fork() will fail if the system does not commit to have memory available for the copy-on-write pages.  Using copy-on-write helps with the performance, but not the size.  With overcommit enabled, Linux will commit more memory (DRAM+swap) than really exits.  But if it runs out, the out of memory manager will come in like a security guard on a United flight and remove a running process.